# Sort values from one workbook into correct worksheets in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very basic question. I have a large Workbook with alot of listed information. I want to take out some of the information into a new workbook and sort it on the different worksheets. I am having some problems with making the code understand which tab I want the information to be placed into. the strName = Range(cell value) do not work and I do not really know what I am doing wrong. How can I make this works? Sorry about the very messy code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strName As String

Set sourceWq = Workbooks("SD KPIs 2014 onwards").Worksheets("VQN+Concessionn")
Set front = Workbooks("databank progging").Worksheets("Frontpage")

 For l = 5 To 30
    For i = 2 To 250000 'Goes through the sourceWq workbook
    If front.Cells(l, 13).Value = sourceWq.Cells(i, 24).Value Then  'Finds correct supplier
        strName = Range("l,13")
        Sheets(strName).Select 'Selects the correct worksheet for the supplier
        For j = 4 To 15 'Month
            If sourceWq.Cells(i, 33).Value = Cells(7, j).Value Then
            For n = 8 To 11 'The type of NCR
                If sourceWq.Cells(i, 27).Value = Cells(n, 2).Value Then
                Cells(n, j).Value = Cells(n, j).Value + 1
                Else: End If
            Next n
            Else: End If
        Next j
        Else: End If
    Next i
Next l

End Sub
```

Comment: in what workbook (`sourceWq` or `front`) your `strName` is located?

Comment: the same question to `Sheets(strName).Select` . In what workbook are you trying to select sheet?

Answer (score 0):

`strName = Range("l,13")` should read `strName = Cells(l,13)`

Comment: or `strName = Cells(l,13)`?

Comment: I used the strName = Cells(l,13), range (l,13) did not work. Now the line Sheets(strName).Select is out of range.. Workbooks("databank progging").Worksheets("strName") does not work either.. What can I use instead? @simoco

Answer (score 0):

I slightly rewrote your code without this loop `For i = 2 To 250000` (I use `Find` method instead):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim strName As String
    Dim sourceWq As Worksheet, front As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    Dim l As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("SD KPIs 2014 onwards")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("databank progging")

    Set sourceWq = wb1.Worksheets("VQN+Concessionn")
    Set front = wb2.Worksheets("Frontpage")

    For l = 5 To 30
        With sourceWq.Range("X2:X250000")
            Set rng = .Find(front.Cells(l, 13).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rng.Address
            Do
                strName = front.Cells(l, 13).Value
                Set sh = wb2.Worksheets(strName)
                With sh
                    For j = 4 To 15 'Month
                        If rng.Offset(, 9).Value = .Cells(7, j).Value Then
                            For n = 8 To 11 'The type of NCR
                                If rng.Offset(, 3).Value = .Cells(n, 2).Value Then
                                    .Cells(n, j).Value = .Cells(n, j).Value + 1
                                End If
                            Next n
                        End If
                    Next j
                End With
                Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
            Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    Next l
End Sub
```